# Access Categories.find({}) result from template helper

Tags: meteor

I'm retrieving a list of categories (and subcategories) from Mongo and I need to bind these values to a list of html elements that represent the categories in the view.

When I retrieve this from the server I save it in a Session object. I'm trying to write a loop that goes through this object and binds the data with `jQuery.data()` to the list html elements.

However I can't access the collection from within the Session object in Meteor. I can in the browser! I can drill down to `categories.collection.queries[1].results` and I can see the category objects. If I use this in Meteor I get undefined error.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks

As suggested in the comments I'm already using `{{#each categories}}` in my template. But once the categories are rendered I want to bind data values to them from the same collection.

Comment: is there a reason why you don't simply use a meteor (blaze) template to list the results? One might ask why you want to use meteor in first place if you then do everything it provides manually using other technology.

Comment: @ChristianFritz is right - you'll find it much easier to do this in blaze. `{{each categories}}...your html...{{/categories}}` and then your helper just needs to return `categories.find()`. No jQuery required.

Comment: I'm already doing that. But I need to bind data to the list elements so when they get selected by the user the values bound to the elements can be sent back to the server.